# On unitary manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

For integer $d$, we can define unitary matrices $\mathbb{U}:=\{U\mid U^*U=UU^*=I_d\}$. This forms a manifold of dimension $d^2$.

Suppose we are given a submanifold of $\mathbb{U}$, denoted as $\mathbb{V}$. We know $\mathbb{V}$ has a nonzero volume in $\mathbb{U}$, or in other words, $\mathbb{V}$ has a dimension the same as the dimension of $d^2$.

Under what condition, we can conclude $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{U}$?

It will be a too strong requirement that $\mathbb{V}$ is a subgroup.

Comment: What kind of condition are you looking for? $\Bbb{V}$ could be any open subset of $\Bbb{U}$ (whose dimension, by the way, is not $d^2$).

Comment: @abx The dimension of $\mathrm{U}_n$ is $d^2$ (it's a real form of $\mathrm{GL}_d$).

Comment: @YCor: Oops, yes of course. I was thinking of $\operatorname{SU}_n $.

Comment: The only open subgroup of a connected Lie group $G$ is $G$, so if $\mathbb{V}$ is a subgroup, it is $\mathbb{U}$.

Comment: It will be a too strong requirement that $\mathbb{V}$ is a subgroup.

Comment: If $\mathbb{V}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{U}$ then $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{U}$.